# FileSystemEventHandler Ignoring/hiding 'similar' multiple answers

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, file-handling, observers

Recently I started in coding using **[python](/questions/tagged/python)** on a Rpi.
I already succeeded to make some little projects using the stack and **[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)** database.

Right now I'm working on a script to create a file version systems that save the changed file in another direction with date and so on.

But right now I am working on the Observer script. 
When it is running it is detecting the files that are changed. But if a single file is changed the script is detecting that multiple times. See output.

I am already detecting if it is only a change in the folder or file. So I can already ignore that also the ~ symbol after the file name I remove already.

I have already tested some different things but nothing is working out.
Do any of you have an idea, to solve this issue?

My Code:

---

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
path='/home/pi/Python/test/Folder/'

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):

        PathVar = event.src_path + '/'
        if PathVar == path:
            print('Change in Folder IGNORE action')
            print()
        else:
#            print("Event!")
            ChangeVarSrc_path = event.src_path
            ChangeVarSrc_path = ChangeVarSrc_path.replace(path, "")  # Remove Path in string
            ChangeVarSrc_path = ChangeVarSrc_path.replace('~', "")  # If ~ exists in string remove

            print(ChangeVarSrc_path)
            print()

            ################# My Idea but not working ################
#           NewAnswer = ChangeVarSrc_path
#           If OldAnswer == NewAnswer:
#               print('Same Answer Ignore')
#           else:
#               print(NewAnswer)
#               OldAnswer = NewAnswer
            ############### Bad Idea not working :) ################


event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

Answer:

---

```
2Observer.py
Change in Folder IGNORE action
2Observer.py
2Observer.py
2Observer.py
2Observer.py
2Observer.py
2Observer.py
2Observer.py
2Observer.py
2Observer.py
2Observer.py
2Observer.py
Change in Folder IGNORE action
```

Answer (score 0):

You watch all events so that’s why you see many entries. You can print `event.event_type` to see them. You can try [on_modified](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler.on_modified) instead.